# antd customized className doesn't show in Chrome dev tool

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd and want to add a className for a component to edit the component's css style, below is my code:

events.js

```
import styles from "./index.less";

<List
  className={styles.events_list}
  itemLayout="vertical"
  size="large"
>
  <List.Item
    className={styles.event_list_item}
    key={item.title}
  />
</List>
```

index.less

```
.event_list_item {
    :global {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

.events_list {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I am adding a className to both the List and List.Item, but when I open the Chrome dev tool elements, I don't see the added class name there.
below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I am not using antd, but it appears you misunderstood, try style={style.events_list} instead of className.

Answer (score 0):

events.js

```
import styles from "./index.less";

<List
  className='event_list_item'
  itemLayout="vertical"
  size="large"
>
  <List.Item
    className='event_list_item'
    key={item.title}
  />
</List>
```

index.less

```
.event_list_item {
    :global {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

.events_list {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Or you are going to use `styles.events_list`, you can use the style instead of className

```
<List
  style={styles.events_list}
  itemLayout="vertical"
  size="large"
>
  <List.Item
    style={styles.event_list_item}
    key={item.title}
  />
</List>
```

Thank you

Comment: What I did is antd recommended way to edit antd component css. I tried your solution but unfortunately, it's not working.

Comment: Are you using styled component? if yes you can use this way 

```
const CustomList = styled(List)`background-color: red; `
```

And if it is not working too, you can check you added less config or not on webpack.